# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementJobService" on path: DexPathList

Tags: java, android

I received a crash from my play store application and here are the logs details, I couldn't figure out that much so any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

````
+ 11 non-project frames
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementJobService" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.mh.systems.abridge-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.mh.systems.abridge-1, /system/lib]]
- 14 non-project frames
1 at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
2 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:501)
3 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:461)
4 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService (ActivityThread.java:2558)
5 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600 (ActivityThread.java:141)
6 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1338)
7 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
8 at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:137)
9 at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5103)
10 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative (Unknown source)
11 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:546)
12 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:737)
13 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:553)
14 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (Unknown source)```
````

Comment: I don't suppose you ever found a fix for this? I am having the same problem. :/

Answer (score 0):

I only get this on Android 4.x devices.  Looks like this is a gms/Firebase/Crashlytics bug.  AppMeasurementJobService gets automatically added to your Manifest.

```
<service
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementJobService"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="false" />
```

The job is close sourced, but as named it appears to extend JobService.  JobService was added in Lollipop, so it goes boom on pre-Lollipop devices.  The smali below would appear to confirm it.

```
.method public constructor <init>()V
    .registers 1

    .line 1
    invoke-direct {p0}, Landroid/app/job/JobService;-><init>()V

    return-void
.end method
```

I assume if you disable Crashlytics/Firebase on pre-Lollipop devices it will "fix" it, but for me that might cause Crashlytics not inited crashes.